# Should I tell my supervisor when I go over him to ask for a raise?

Tags: raise, performance-reviews

It's not malicious or anything, it's just how things are handled at my company. It's a small business (15-20 people). The CEO handles hiring and raises and the like.

I'm about a week away from my next performance review, and that will be given to me by my supervisor (let's call him Jim). Jim is the one who I've reported to all year and best understands how I've done, so it's almost a certainty that the CEO will talk to him when I ask for a raise. I should note that I'll be asking for more than the standard raise, thus the likelihood of Jim getting pulled into it.

Should I mention it in the review? Couching it as a "heads up, CEO might talk to you about my performance because I asked for a raise". If so, how much information should I divulge to him, either voluntarily or solicited?

Comment: Why do you need to leave your supervisor out of the loop?  What advantage do you think you will gain by not telling him first?

Comment: IDK. The internet is full of advice for raises and negotiation that boil down to reveal as little as possible. It's seemed a little counter intuitive here, hence the question.

Comment: @wicbuj For adversarial negotiations revealing little is advisable but in this circumstance your supervisor doesn't fit into that model.  They will come in as advisor to the negotiator.  Giving them warning allows them to prepare the advice they will offer.  If you think they will give more favorable advice when pre-informed go that route.  I know that I'd be more likely to sing strong praises if I were given a heads up that it was being asked of me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Definitely tell him right away. The last thing you want is for your immediate supervisor to be taken off guard with the suggestion form the CEO. He should be able to defend it, and that is likely to take a little forethought. He's also likely to feel undermined, even if it is the normal process in your office.

Comment: Definitely agree with this - if you want a "more than standard" raise then you want to your supervisor on your side and supporting you

Comment: Plus, it's likely that your boss can offer you some advice on how to approach the CEO. They've been around longer and probably know the CEO better than you.